# Can geometry nodes export gltf format?

Tags: geometry-nodes, gltf

Applying modifiers doesn't seem to work for it . Is there any way to export gltf format When I use geometry nodes?

Answer (score 1):

When you use the export dialogue in *File>Export>GLTF* make sure to also choose *apply modifiers* in the export options. Then the GN modifier will be applied on export rather than the input geometry only.

[image]

Comment: The question mentions that "Apply Modifiers" doesn't work for the case of Geometry Nodes.

Comment: Ah, @scurest has the answer: If you add a "Realize Instances" node, you can get "Apply Modifiers" to work.  https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/1537#issuecomment-1013921811

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Export animation as alembic .abc with face sets option activated for material support.
2. Import .abc on Blender.
3. Bake animation with *Object > Animation > Bake Action > Visual Keying to Object*.
4. Export as .gltf